# Compute spheres 2D speeds in perspective projected animations

Tags: animation, 3d, velocity, perspectivecamera

I created two animations that consist of spheres moving in a perspective projected 3D space, which means that the size and speed of the spheres vary with the distance: they increase when they are closer to the viewer (the camera) and decrease when they move farther away from the viewer. Both animations are played on a computer 2D screen.

In the **Random Movement Animation**, the spheres are moving randomly in different directions (GIF 1). In my code, I computed their spherical coordinates (sphere.position.xyz) with the two angles theta and Phi (see below the formulas used for the position and their derivates).

In the **Optic Flow Animation**, it is the camera that moves along the z-axis (camera_z -= .1) and the spheres don't move (GIF 2).

In the context of a neuroscientific experiment, I need to match the perception of speed between the two animations, thus I need to first compute the 2D speed in both animations (By 2D, I refer to the **screen coordinates** rather than the world coordinates). What are the respective speed formulas for each animation? Does the speed of each sphere in the optic flow calculation equal to the camera's speed?

[image]

[image]

How I generated Spheres coordinates in the Random animation:

```
for sphere in spheres:

        sphere.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-25, 25, size=2)
        z = np.random.uniform(near_z, far_z)

        sphere.position.z = z
        sphere.position.x *= z/-50
        sphere.position.y *= z/-50

        sphere.theta_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360
        sphere.phi_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360

        theta_rad = sphere.theta_deg * np.pi / 180
        phi_rad = sphere.phi_deg* np.pi / 180

        sphere.dx = speed * np.sin(-phi_rad - theta_rad) / frameRate
        sphere.dy = -speed * np.cos(phi_rad + theta_rad) / frameRate
        sphere.dz = -speed * np.cos(theta_rad) / frameRate
```